# Trouble Parsing JSON File and using an API PUSH for selected fields

Tags: python, json, linux, bash, shell

I am looking for advice on how to parse a file and select certain fields.
The selected fields then need to be included in an API push to a separate system using curl.

The challenge is that the amount of fields needed may vary each time the file is populated. I can however use the keys `"key"` and the values provided after that in `"value"`.

So in the following example I'm wanting to capture these values (though a separate message may have more or less):

```
{
    "result": {
        "problems": [{
            "id": "8103182743126107297_1579010239089V2",
            "startTime": 1579010239089,
            "endTime": -1,
            "displayName": "297",
            "impactLevel": "INFRASTRUCTURE",
            "status": "OPEN",
            "severityLevel": "AVAILABILITY",
            "commentCount": 0,
            "tagsOfAffectedEntities": [{
                "context": "CONTEXTLESS",
                "key": "JBOSS"
            }, {
                "context": "CONTEXTLESS",
                "key": "AC"
            }, {
                "context": "CONTEXTLESS",
                "key": "Host Name",
                "value": "servernameX.com"
            }, {
                "context": "CONTEXTLESS",
                "key": "Tomcat"
            }],
            "rankedImpacts": [{
                "entityId": "PROCESS_GROUP_INSTANCE-2XXXE58A78A142D7",
                "entityName": "service Tomcat *",
                "severityLevel": "AVAILABILITY",
                "impactLevel": "INFRASTRUCTURE",
                "eventType": "PROCESS_UNAVAILABLE"
            }, {
                "entityId": "PROCESS_GROUP_INSTANCE-A2F65660B538D9CF",
                "entityName": "JBoss EAP",
                "severityLevel": "AVAILABILITY",
                "impactLevel": "INFRASTRUCTURE",
                "eventType": "PROCESS_UNAVAILABLE"
            }],
            "affectedCounts": {
                "INFRASTRUCTURE": 2,
                "SERVICE": 0,
                "APPLICATION": 0,
                "ENVIRONMENT": 0
            },
            "recoveredCounts": {
                "INFRASTRUCTURE": 0,
                "SERVICE": 0,
                "APPLICATION": 0,
                "ENVIRONMENT": 0
            },
            "hasRootCause": true
        }],
        "monitored": {
            "INFRASTRUCTURE": 235,
            "SERVICE": 19,
            "APPLICATION": 1,
            "ENVIRONMENT": 1
        }
    }
}
```

Then... once those values are captured, convert them into a new JSON string like this (only the value of `"Host"` will change):

```
{
    "State": "OPEN",
    "ProblemID": "55555",
    "ImpactedEntity": "Alert from Maintenance Window",
    "ProblemTitle": "Process unavailable",
    "Host": "captured value 1(JBOSS), captured value 2(AC), captured value 3(HostName), captured value 4(servernameX.com),captured value 5(Tomcat), "
}
```

I need to fit them into an curl POST and have it execute.

```
curl -v -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '(the JSON above)' 'http://serverA.com/?apiKey=8675309:p'
```

This is a Linux box and I have python 2.7 available on it

**So to summarize:**

- We need to parse a flat file for the values of interest (call it
  file.x The amount of values may vary but there is always a key
  word/s to identify)
- We need to take those values of interest and place them in a CURL
  statement that does an API push (The format is listed above)

How can this be accomplished? Ultimately I will be scheduling this in a cron task for different times.
Please advise and thank you so kindly all !

Comment: I believe you'd benefit from using the `jq` package which will help you parse and search for values.
While not a complete answer, please consider it as a lead. 
More info at https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/

Comment: I have tried to reformat your question as to both be more readable *and* contain syntactically valid JSON (making parts of source code bold does not work on this website, but having actual working code people can copy easily outweighs that). Please check that I did not get the details wrong.

Comment: There's a lot of logic implied by your sample inputs and outputs that isn't fleshed out in the question (f/e, needing a lookup table that can map `PROCESS_UNAVAILABLE` to `Process unavailable`; knowing how to pick which "ranked impact" to report when there's more than one; etc).

Comment: ...implicitly requiring an answer to intuit and address those details generally goes outside the scope of what can be considered a reasonable Stack Overflow question; can you try to narrow it down to content that (1) you don't know how to do, which (2) isn't already covered by existing Q&A entries (like [Parsing JSON with UNIX tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools))?

Comment: Thank you for the edit on format

Comment: Your sample is not fully consistent because there is `"key": "Tomcat"` and I don't see a reason why it would be the only one that doen't appear in the output.

Comment: Thank you Tomalek, this was an error of omission. I have added it

Comment: @runatyr if you're open to install `jtc` utility (I'm the developer), then I can provide you with the exact solution to your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `jq` is available, would you try the following:

```
i=1
while IFS=$'\n' read -r x; do
    str+=$(printf "captured value %d(%s), " "$i" "$x")
    ((i++))
done < <(jq -r '.. | .key? // empty, .value? // empty' < file.json)

cat <<EOS
{
    "State": "OPEN",
    "ProblemID": "55555",
    "ImpactedEntity": "Alert from Maintenance Window",
    "ProblemTitle": "Process unavailable",
    "Host": "$str"
}
EOS
```

Output:

```
{
    "State": "OPEN",
    "ProblemID": "55555",
    "ImpactedEntity": "Alert from Maintenance Window",
    "ProblemTitle": "Process unavailable",
    "Host": "captured value 1(JBOSS), captured value 2(AC), captured value 3(Host Name), captured value 4(servernameX.com), captured value 5(Tomcat), "
}
```

If you want to assign a variable `json` to the output above, modify the `cat` statement as:

```
json=$(cat <<EOS
{
    "State": "OPEN",
    "ProblemID": "55555",
    "ImpactedEntity": "Alert from Maintenance Window",
    "ProblemTitle": "Process unavailable",
    "Host": "$str"
}
EOS
)
```

Then you can embed the variable `json` in the `curl` command line.

**[Explanations]**

- The filter `..` for the `jq` command traverses the `json` tree recursively and get all the
  values keyed by `.key` or `.value`. The `null` values are removed with `// empty`.
- The output of the `jq` command is fed to the `while` loop and the formatted values are appended to the string `str` one by one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! getting jq on the system will not be an issue other than scheduling it for a production system :) I'll run this through test again but this is really clean and almost self explanatory, even for a person who does not get to do python as much as they would like. As an FYI, this is being leveraged for a monitoring system that currently has some limitations. Just wanted to say thank you again :)

Comment: @runatyr Thanks for the feedback. It's my pleasure to know it's working well. Good luck!